# Understanding what a model is in regards to Tensorflow and object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm starting to dive into tensor and object detection for a drone my friend and I are building. I keep seeing the word "model" thrown around and I'm sorry but I don't know what I should be picturing when I see the word "model" in terms of tensorflow and object detection.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in deep learning model is simply architecture of a neural network. It defines type of layers, number of nodes, connections, etc. Tensorflow uses static graph, which describes your model architecture in terms of nodes and operations. As a start you can use Keras API for defining your model.
https://keras.io/
Also read more about TF graph https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs and take a look at tutorials https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials